# Ссылка с всплывающей подсказкой?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Для незарегистрированных пользователей в форме ответа показывается справка. В том числе имеется следующий фрагмент про ссылки:

> Можно добавлять всплывающие подсказки к ссылкам:
>
> ```
> Нажмите [здесь](http://diy.stackexchange.com «этот текст появляется при наведении курсора мыши»)!
> Это также работает для [ссылок в виде сноски][blog].
>
>  [blog]: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/ «нажмите здесь, чтобы получить обновления»
> ```

Но если скорпипастить предлагаемый код в ответ, то видно, что это не работает:

[image: Скриншот]

---

### Демо

Нажмите [здесь](http://diy.stackexchange.com «этот текст появляется при наведении курсора мыши»)!
Это также работает для [ссылок в виде сноски][blog].

[blog]: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/ «нажмите здесь, чтобы получить обновления»

Comment: Кстати, зарегистрированный пользователь тоже увидит эту справку, если нажмёт на серый вопросик в правой части панели ответа.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нужны [обычные кавычки](https://goo.gl/gKCb9e)

```
Нужны [обычные кавычки](https://goo.gl/gKCb9e "а не лапки")
```

Comment: Всё равно баг и надо справку править. Я вообще думал, что кавычки декоративные и важен только пробел.

Comment: @Qwertiy Согласен. Мой ответ - не голос против, а дополнение о том, какое исправление нужно.